# Google HostedMatch data format

Tags: exchange-server

We are using Google's Hosted Match data service to store information. The information is written by a 3-rd party vendor and then sent to us. I am trying to find out the format Google send the data in the protobuf message. Their spec says the data written to the table should be Base64 encoded, our 3rd party vendor says they are doing that but the data in the message seems to be Base64 decoded by Google.

Is this correct, do Google Base64 the data before sending it to us, or is our vendor doing something incorrect?

(I've asked Google but they take a long time to reply to emails)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the data is base64 decoded before being put in the bid request message.